# Heroku, can't get server side code to run

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, server-side

Started coding this year. Trying to deploy my app on Heroku, but server side code isnt working, thus cannot connect to database. I also have a login page, but it won't let me log in with the right credentials, instead I get this error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Works fine locally.

Context:
Locally, I usually run "npm start" on my root directory and on an additional terminal, "cd server" & "node index.js" to run my server side code.

Attempt 1:
Initially, I was running "npm start" on my Procfile, located in my root directory. As I mentioned, it only runs the app, but doesn't run the server side code.

Attempt 2:
I replaced "npm start" with "npm run start-both" in my Procfile, and added a script in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start-server": "cd server && node server.js",
    "start-both": "concurrently 'npm start' 'npm run start-server'"
  },
```

Locally (through VisualStudio Code), this runs both the app and server side code with one command. However, in Heroku, after I've updated the git repository and uploaded the code through "git push", I still have the same issue, where the server side code doesn't seem to be working (this is a assumption based on the fact that I cannot login through my login page).

I've actually checked the logs using the "heroku logs" command in my Hyper terminal. It seems like in the logs its still using the previous code "cd server && npm start". I'm not sure why its not updating, or if the issue lies somewhere else, but I would really love some help on how to properly host my app on heroku. Thank you in advance.

For some extra context:

I believe I'm using the language Node.js.

Here is my file structure:

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPjGe.png)